# Webview on react navive

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am making an app on react native, that connect to a webservice and bring me back a JSON with an HTML inside.

I have to display that HTML, and for that I am using a WebView. The problem is that I want my HTML image take the entire width of the screen.

```
 let {response} = this.state;
    let {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        return (
                <WebView
                    style={{width: width, backgroundColor: "red"}}
                    ref={'webview'}
                    startInLoadingState
                    source={{html: response}}
                    injectedJavaScript={`meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1;`}
                />
        )
    }
```

This is on my iPhone 7 plus:

[image: The image fails to grab the entire width of the screen]

[image: This is the way is suppose to look, edge to edge, it doesn't matter the device]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this npm moodule:

```
react-native-htmlview
```

In this use can define own styles.

Answer (score 0):

add `alignSelf: "stretch"` to items style.